# Auto Completion with auto-complete OR predictive based on mode

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, latex, auctex

I'm using `emacs-snapshot` (24.2.50) on Xubuntu 12.10. For completion I am currently using `auto-complete` (v1.4).

I have a pretty nice setup of `auto-complete` with various sources, including the `semantic` source for code completion of my c++ programming. However, I'd like to switch to `predictive-mode` for completion of LaTeX documents (I'm using `AUCTeX` for all LaTeX related stuff).

My current `auto-complete` config (for LaTeX; I omitted all non-LaTeX config) looks like this:

```lisp
(require 'auto-complete-latex)
(require 'ac-math)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'latex-mode) ; make auto-complete aware of {{{latex-mode}}}
(defun ac-latex-mode-setup ()       ; add ac-sources to default ac-sources
  (setq ac-sources
     (append '(ac-source-math-latex ac-source-latex-commands)
           ac-sources))
)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'ac-latex-mode-setup)
```

After adding `predictive` to the `load-path` and doing the `auto-load` stuff as described [here](http://www.dr-qubit.org/predictive/predictive-user-manual/html/Obtaining-and-Installing.html) I tried to disable `auto-complete` for `LaTeX-mode` and enable `predictive-mode` in turn by exchanging the above code by this:

```lisp
(defun ele/latex-mode-completion-setup ()
  (auto-complete-mode -1)
  (predictive-mode 1)
  )
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'ele/latex-mode-completion-setup)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected: `auto-complete` is actually disabled **but** `predictive-mode` is not enabled **and** instead of using `AUCTeX` the build-in `tex-mode` is used.

I have uploaded all LaTeX related config [here](http://pastebin.com/fVnGyhRw). Note that this is loaded *after* the above completion setup, but this is the case for the old `auto-complete` based setup as well. Also note that exchanging that order does not make a difference as far as I can tell. Furthermore I found that simply commenting the `auto-complete` config (first snippet I posted) results in the same behaviour: `tex-mode` is used instead of `AUCTeX`.

I don't want to switch to `predictive-mode` for all modes but I really like many features it provides when doing LaTeX editing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

(remove-hook

might clear the hook, not to run unwanted stuff - just a suggestion indeed

Comment: I'm not really clear what your suggestion is? Call `remove-hook` on the `LaTeX-mode-hook` (maybe in combination with `ac-latex-mode-setup`)? To what end would I do that?